# Select and copy a specific number of filtered rows using VBA in excel

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I'm using AutoFilter on a huge list and want to copy the first visible 200 rows. My code is static since it only select down to row 201. I want to have a dynamic code where I select the first visible 200 rows when filter is used (excluding header). This is how my code looks today:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A2:A201").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Please check this link http://www.thesmallman.com/blog/2016/11/27/copypaste-top-n-visible-rows it has your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link! This helped me to get the solution. I posted my final VBA-code below.

Comment: np. you should avoid using `.Select` in your code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how I solved it!**

The first 200 visible rows are copied from Sheet1 A11 (2 columns) to Sheet2 A2.
And also 200 rows from Sheet1 K11 (3 columns) to Sheet2 G2. If you want to add more copy/paste just add this segment:

```
Set r = Range("K11", Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(12)
Range(r(1), rWC).Resize(, 3).SpecialCells(12).Copy Sheet2.[G2]
```

**Here's the total macro:**

```
Sub

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Dim i As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim rWC As Range


Set r = Range("A11", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(12)
For Each rWC In r
    i = i + 1
    If i = 200 Or i = r.Count Then Exit For
Next rWC
Range(r(1), rWC).Resize(, 2).SpecialCells(12).Copy Sheet2.[A2]


Set r = Range("K11", Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(12)
Range(r(1), rWC).Resize(, 3).SpecialCells(12).Copy Sheet2.[G2]


Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1").Select


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This will copy only the first visible 200 items in column **A**, excluding the header:

```
Sub AutoFilterCopyVisible()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Resize(200, 1)
    Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    r1.Copy r2
End Sub
```

Comment: This does still only copy the first 200 rows, not the first visible 200 rows. I only get 134 rows copied to Sheet2.